# How to inject global variables into all templates?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

In my twig template there are some variables that are required on each page like `userName`, `userId` or `userImage`.

What is the best way to inject them into the template?

I already read the article [How to Inject Variables into all Templates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html) but how could I write a variable (e.g. current user) into the `config/packages/twig.php` file?

Right now there is code like this in every controller:

```php
return $this->render('admin/users/index.html.twig', [
   "allUsers" => $allUsers,
   "pageTitle" => "Benutzerübersicht",
   "userName" => "Max Mustermann",
   "userId" => 5,
   "userImage" => "http://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=6"
]);
```

(These are only example values as I didn't integrate the Authentication yet but wanted to create my template)

Is there any better way than injecting every variable in each controller?

Comment: If all you need is the current user information then [app.user](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/app_variable.html) is already available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have several options, depending exactly on what do you need:

#### You could inject this as Twig global variables using an Event Listener.

1. Create a listener class:

```php
namespace App\Listener;
// src/EventListener/ControllerListener.php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Twig\Environment;

class ControllerListener {
    /**
     * @var \Twig\Environment
     */
    private $twig;
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $manager;
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security
     */
    private $security;

    public function __construct( Environment $twig, EntityManager $manager, Security $security ) {
        $this->twig     = $twig;
        $this->manager  = $manager;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onKernelController( FilterControllerEvent $event ): void {
        $results = $this->manager->getRepository( 'SomeClass' )->findBy( [ 'some' => 'criteria' ] );
        $user    = $this->security->getUser();
        $this->twig->addGlobal( 'veryGlobal', $results[0]->getName() );
        $this->twig->addGlobal( 'username', $user->getUsername() );
    }
}
```

I'm injecting:

- Twig, so you can add the global variables there.
- Entity Manager, so you can query the DB if you need to grab info from there
- Security, to grab information from the user.

2. After this is created, you need to add this configuration lines:

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\EventListener\ControllerListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller }
```

which will enable the event listener to run on each request.

#### Use twig configuration to inject a service-as-a-global:

With these configuration lines, as described in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services), you tell twig to inject a specific service:

```yaml
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        # the value is the service's id
        users: '@App\Service\UserManagement'
```

Then it's as simple as creating `App\Service\UserManagement`:

```php
namespace App\Service:

class UserManagement {

   public function __construct() {
      // use the constructor to inject your dependencies, as usual
   }

   public function getOldestUser() {
      // do your thing
      return $oldestUserName;
   }
}
```

Then from twig you can do:

```
{{ users.oldestUser }}
```

**Note** that every time you called `users.OldestUser` the method will be executed, which could be resource intensive depending on what you are doing. Caching the result on a local property for that service would probably be a good idea.

#### Finally, if you are only interested in logged-in user data

As others mentioned, if you are only interested in data belonging to the logged-in user, you can simply access it [through the app variable, which is injected on each request](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/app_variable.html).

> The representation of the current user or null if there is none. The value stored in this variable can be a UserInterface object, any other object which implements a __toString() method or even a regular string.

For example:

```
{{ app.user.userName }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you implementing the UserInterface? If so you can use `app.user` as described in https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/app_variable.html

e.g. in your templates you can use `{{ app.user.userName }}` to display the current logged in users username.