# how can i pass an objects to my base template in symfony without using render function?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i just create a project and in my `base.html.twig` i put all my stylesheet links, scripts plus my navbar and my footer but when i tried to add some dynamic  informations to the footer and the navbar i couldn't find any solution to pass those objects to my base template without using the render,route functions.

this is my controller

```
class BaseController extends AbstractController
{

    public function index()
    {

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(SettingContact::class);
        $Contact=$em->findAll();

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(SettingWebsite::class);
        $WebSite=$em->findAll();

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(SocialMedia::class);
        $SocialMedia=$em->findAll();

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Services::class);
        $Services=$em->findAll();

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Projects::class);
        $Projects=$em->findAll();

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Customers::class);
        $Customers=$em->findAll();

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Category::class);
        $Category=$em->findAll();

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(AboutUs::class);
        $AboutUs=$em->findAll();


        return $this->render('base.html.twig',[
            'contact'=>$Contact,'website'=>$WebSite,'socialMedia'=>$SocialMedia,
            'services'=>$Services,'project'=>$Projects,

        ]);
    }
}
```

this is my twig :

```
{% for contact in contact %}
{{ contact.email}}
{{ contact.phone}}
{% endfor %}
```

the error: (`Notice: Undefined index: contact`) any solutions pls

Comment: In the render method you send $Contact but you haven’t defined it

Comment: take a look at twig extensions and provide to it the required dependencies ;o)

Comment: @Jakumi i update my post and i think that my twig is fine !

Comment: symfony itself uses a twig extension to provide to twig the `route` function (and the `app` variable, but that's a bit more complicated) and you could use that approach to provide general stuff to your header/footer. besides that, I would claim it's not smart to name the loop variable the same as the array variable (`for var in var`)...

Comment: @Jakumi  i change the variable to {% for contacts in contact %}
{{ contacts.email}}
{{ contacts.phone}}
{% endfor %} but i got  this error Variable "contact" does not exist !! :( and i think that my function do not pass the variable to the twig

Comment: true, that's what Svetoslav said first. however, your question first asked something else ;o)

Comment: @ jakumi oops sorry , i m the noob here xD ! but why it work for the other function and  not this one , i did watch a lot of youtube videos and that how everyone pass variables to the twig !

Comment: Why are you trying to render base.html.twig directly?  Normally this file is extended by an actual page template such as index.html.twig..

Comment: @Cerad cause i m trying to add some dynamic variables to my footer and the nav like contact information (adresse and phone number )

Comment: @Varus Itseems to me that you did not answer to two points that where raised earlier :

1. In 'contact'=>$Contact where is the variable $Contact defined ? I don't see a line in your code with $Contact= <something>

2. Do you really want to loop in a contact variable or do you want to diplay properties (email, phone, etc) for a single contact ? Because in the second case you do not need a loop at all.

Comment: @Varus Still makes no sense to be rendering base.html.twig directly.  I think you are misunderstanding some basic controller/twig concepts.  Might want to review the [template docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#template-inheritance-and-layouts).  Hint: for your nav you probably want a dedicated nav.html.twig file and you probably want to use an [embedded controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers) to inject the necessary values.

Comment: @Giorgiolino i just miss it when i did the copy/paste, i did update the post thnks for noting that , second thing when i start to make a my web app i did notice that im copy past the same code for the nav and footer in every single template so since im alredy extend from the base i just add the code at the base template... now that i need to call my contact data from the db i need to inject them into the base template

Comment: @Giorgiolino i can use the Globals variables !? something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55935615/how-to-inject-global-variables-into-all-templates/55935970

Comment: @Varus. Yes exactly (as you have already figured out). Bonus point for you for figuring it out by yourself. That's the best way to effectively learn. Remember "Knowledge Comes from experience. Information is not knowledge."- Albert Einstein.

Answer (score 1):

after all that I finally made it, and i wanna thank every one of u guys u help me a lot !
and what i did is i create a new service and i used twig to inject it as a global

this is my class :

```
<?php
namespace App\Service ;

use AppEntitySettingContact;
use DoctrineORMEntityManagerInterface;
use SymfonyComponentHttpKernelEventFilterControllerEvent;
use TwigEnvironment;

class ContactManagement 
{
    
    
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $manager;

    public function __construct( Environment $twig,EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
       
        $this->manager     =$manager;
        
    }

    public function showContact()
    {
        $result = $this->manager->getRepository(SettingContact::class);
        $contact=$result->findAll();

        return $contact;
    }

}
```

the twig file

```
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    globals:
        ga_tracking: '@App\Service\ContactManagement'
```