# Symfony: How to make variable work on every page?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a question for my Symfony project.

I have this code which shows the number of rows in a given database table:

```
// BudgetRepository
public function countBudgets()
{
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('budget');
  return $qb
    ->select('count(budget.id)')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

```
// BudgetController
public function all(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
  $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Budget::class);
  $count = $repository->countBudgets();
  return $this->render("budget/budget.html.twig", ['numberOfBudgets' => $count]);
}
```

It works, but it only works inside `budget/budget.html.twig` by usung `{{ numberOfBudgets }}`.

How can I make it work on every page (specifically I want it to be placed in my file called `_sidebar.html.twig`? Right now if I place `{{ numberOfBudgets }}` onto `_sidebar.html.twig` I get this error message "Variable "numberOfBudgets" does not exist".

How should I rewrite the code?

Comment: What's the relationship between `budget.html.twig` and `_sidebar.html.twig`? When and how are you rendering this sidebar? I would imagine the sidebar is not rendered independently, right?

Comment: @yivi It's rendered at the beginning of the base.html.twig page (right after the opening body-tag) by using `{{ include('_sidebar.html.twig') }}`

Comment: Something is wrong then. If the template was included just as you say, the variable **would be visible as well**. From the docs: "Included templates have access to the variables of the active context.". (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/include.html)

Comment: You'll need to include minimal twig examples that reliably reproduce the issue.

Comment: @yivi I think you have misunderstood - or more likely that I haven't been totally clear. It does work on both the base file and the sidebar file - but if I place `{{ numberOfBudgets }}` on the sidebar and open a different URL then it the error "Variable "numberOfBudgets" occours. Probably because the variable is set to only page/URL only. Should I then go for global twig variables?

Comment: You have several options here. [How to inject global variables into all templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55935970/1426539)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use global twig variable.
Move Your code to service:

```
class BudgetService
{
    public function all(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Budget::class);
        return $repository->countBudgets();
    }
}
```

Then register global variable in twig configuration (config/packages/twig.yaml):

```
twig:
  globals:
    budget: '@App\Services\BudgetService'
```

Then You can use it in any template like:

```
Total: {{ budget.all }}
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I'm afraid this is not really relevant here. The question is not about "global twig variables", simply about a visibility problem across included templates (something that would not require creating a global variable at all)

Comment: And if the question **was** about creating global twig variables, there are tons of dupes to choose from :)

Comment: Sometimes people don't know that global twig variables exists :)

Comment: @BogdanKuštan Hello Bogdan! Thanks for the example. That works - almost - I get the following error, and how do I solve it? `Too few arguments to function App\Service\BudgetService::all(), 0 passed in \budget\vendor\twig\twig\src\Extension\CoreExtension.php on line 1599 and exactly 1 expected` - I do understand the error, but how do I fix it? How can I leave out the argument in all()?

Comment: @FreePalestine I would use constructor injection and inject EntityManager (or even better BudgetRepository directly) in __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) then assign it to some private variable ($this->entityManager = $entityManager).

Comment: @BogdanKuštan Thank you - I really appreciate the help. I fixed it by injecting BudgetRepository directly :-)))

Answer (score -1):

I would go for a session variable, take a look at [Symfony Session](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html#basic-usage) to access your count variable but make sure to update this var in session if any change occurs.

```
public function index(EntityManagerInterface $em) 
{
    $count = $em->getRepository(Budget::class)->countBudgets();

    $session = $this->requestStack->getSession();
    $session->set('budgetCount', $count);
}
```

To access the session var in your twig template, take a look at [App global variable](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#the-app-global-variable).

```
<p>Total budgets: {{ app;session.budgetCount }}</p>
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I'm afraid this is wrong. The question is not about having a value persist across requests (which the session would help with), but simply about variable visibility across included templates.

Comment: Well, I though that persist his var in session was enabling him to access it from any twig template, which make it visible for any template no ? (correct me if I'm wrong, it's only for understanding !)